# Can husband deported from UK apply again as spouse?

Tags: uk, spouses, deportation

I am going to the UK with a work permit. My husband got deported from the UK in 2014 because he stayed illegally on a student visa.

Can my husband apply again as a spouse?

Comment: Can he apply? Yes. Will he get it? Most probably not.

Comment: Your husband has established a record of visa abuse. Why should UK Immigration believe that he won't abuse the system again? If you can answer that then he might have a chance of getting a visa. If not then you should probably save the application fee.

Comment: Does "as a spouse" mean to move to the UK for settlement? If so, the preceding comments may be wrong, but you should ask at [Expatriates.SE] to get a good answer, since settlement visas are off topic here.

Comment: @CannonFodder if he's applying for a spouse visa then staying indefinitely in the UK would not be an abuse of the system.  Is that reason enough for UKVI to believe that he won't abuse the system?